# Chamando dicionário em outro View Controller Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, dicionário

Estou tentando passar uma dicionário de um ViewController para outro, obtive sucesso, porém o dicionário que eu estou passando é o vazio. Eu quero passar o dicionário após ser adicionadas o userInput quando clicar no botão de save (createFav)

Este é meu ViewController onde estou pegando o input do usuário e inserindo no dicionário:

```
    var favsDictionary = [String: String]()
    var rowsInSection = 1

    @IBAction func createFav(sender: AnyObject) {
        var userInputToTrimm = userInput.text
        var trimmUserInput = userInputToTrimm.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
        var zipInStr: String = zipCode.text!

        //Este if/else confere se a entrada do usuario não é nulo
        if (userInputToTrimm == String()){
            println("Please insert a name")
        } else if (trimmUserInput == String()) {
            println("Please input a valid name")
        } else {

            favsDictionary[trimmUserInput] = zipInStr

        }
    }
```

E este é como estou importando o favsDict no outro View:

```
var cellDictionary = ViewController().favsDictionary
```

Comment: Fiquei um pouco confuso com os nomes que você utilizou. Teria como você refatorar os nomes? Por exemplo, de onde você pegou o textInput? o que é newTextInput? Se puder, dê uma lida aqui: [Coding Horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/)

Comment: Melhorei as variáveis, espero que esteja mais claro.

Comment: Este já é o seu código todo? Como você está fazendo a transição das telas? Da forma que você está tentando obter os dados de `ViewController` distintas não é o caminho, por isso pergunto da transição pois a forma correta é por aí.

Comment: Não este não é o código todo, porém acabei de conseguir resolver o problema, era so criar o dicionario em um arquivo do swift que nao fosse uma View

Answer (score 1):

Ola, vi que resolveu o problema e isso geralmente importa, mas não posso ignorar o seu caso, e como o padrão de projeto MVC te facilitaria. Provavelmente você pode ter feito algo sem saber sobre padrões.

Usei também o Singleton dentro da classe modelo pois o Singleton faz com que sua classe use uma única instancia, logo você compartilhar informação. (Tem que gente que gosta e tem gente que odeia)

Padrões é bom conhecer, foram anos de construção na programação, mas padrões são feitos para facilitar.

Fiz um exemplo que simula sua situação no PlayGround

```
import UIKit

class ViewController
{
    init()
    {
        Favoritos.shared.adicionar("fav1", zipCode: "01");
        Favoritos.shared.adicionar("fav2", zipCode: "02");
        Favoritos.shared.adicionar("fav3", zipCode: "03");

        Favoritos.shared.select("fav2");
    }
 }

 class ViewController2
 {

    init()
    {
         println("Selecionou na outra viewcontroller o favorito "+Favoritos.shared.getSelected()!);

        ///aqui vc vai na sua view e muda o texto
    }
  }

 //Nosso modelo
 class Favoritos {

    //padrao singleton
    class var shared: Favoritos 
    {
        struct Static {
            static let instance: Favoritos = Favoritos()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    private var dicFavoritos:[String:String] = [String:String]();
    private var selected:String?;

    func adicionar(name:String, zipCode:String)
    {
        //Aqui vc faz toda a logica de validacao como preferir, com ou sem Regexp
        if (name == String()){
            println("Please insert a name")
        } else if (zipCode == String()) {
            println("Please input a valid name")
        } else {
            dicFavoritos[name] = zipCode
        }
    }

   func getFavoritoByName(name:String)->String?
   {
        return dicFavoritos[name]!;
   }

   func select(name:String)
   {
        selected = getFavoritoByName(name)!;
   }

   func getSelected()->String?
   {
        return selected;
   }   
 }


 let viewController = ViewController();
 let viewController2 = ViewController2();
```

Se quiser se aprofundar mais existe em inglês uma boa aula e ele fala sobre MVC de forma bem clara. [São aulas de Stanford grátis pelo Itunes U.](https://itunes.apple.com/br/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099)

Espero que tenha contribuido